# How to split app-routing.module.ts in multiple files in Angular 2?

Tags: angular2-routing

Considering the image, I have a component (1) + module (2) + routing (3)(in "app-routing.module.ts"). To avoid too much code in "app-routing.module.ts", I want to move the routing code (3) in other file (suppose "product.routes.ts"). How can I do this considering I'm using Angular 2? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the `AppComponentRoutingModule` which I use, which can be extended with further files, usually that is one routes file per nested routing (to be imported in the corresponding module). The components and routes may vary, but it generally works alike this (guards skipped for the sake of brevity):

Create `src/app/routes/app.routes.ts` with content alike:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorPage } from 'src/app/pages/error/error.page';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path:          '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }, // main entry point.
  { path:      'home', loadChildren: () => import('src/app/pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
  { path: 'error/:id', component: ErrorPage, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path:        '**', redirectTo: '/error/404' }
];
```

The nested routes don't look much different, for example `src/app/routes/home.routes.ts`:

```
export const homeRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: HomePage,
  children: [
    ...
  ]
}];
```

Create `src/app/app.component.routing.module.ts` with content alike:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './routes/app.routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppComponentRoutingModule {}
```

Then import `AppComponentRoutingModule` in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from 'src/app/app.component';
import { AppComponentRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app.component.routing.module';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    AppComponentRoutingModule,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In order to enable verbose logging, `enableTracing: true` is your friend.